# Kendo UI MVC. How to update Grid and add new value in $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read()

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to update Grid after I update data in the database by calling

`$('#ExchangeGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();`

I need to update grid with current DateTime but grid is updating with time that are present in DateTimePicker()

How can I change the time to current?

My Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Internal.Models.ExchangeRateData>()
.Name("ExchangeGrid") 
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.originCurrencyFormated);
    columns.Bound(p => p.targetCurrencyFormated);
    columns.Bound(p => p.rate);
    columns.Bound(p => p.percentage) ;  
    columns.Command(commands => { commands.Edit(); }); 
    columns.Bound(p => p.adjustedRate) ;

}) 
.Editable(edit =>
{
    edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine); 
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(item => item.targetCurrency); 
    })
    .Events(events =>
    {
        events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");  
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("ExchangeRate_Read", "MyController").Data("ReadRequestData"))
    .Update(c => c.Action("Currencies_Update", "MyControllor")) 
    ) 
)
```

When I update Grid function "ReadRequestData" is called

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ExchangeRate_Read", "MyController").Data("ReadRequestData"))
```

In this function value of "date" is populated from DateTimePicker

```
function ReadRequestData() {
    return { 
        "date": $('#dateList').val()
    };
}
```

Code for DateTimePicker:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
  .Name("dateList")
  .Start(CalendarView.Month) 
  .Format("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss")
  .Value(DateTime.Now) 
  .Events(e => e.Change("changeDate"))
)
```

Code for function onRequestEnd(e)

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {

    if (e.type == "update") { 
        $('#ExchangeGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

I need to update several columns after InLine Edit but automatically only column that have been change is updated. I also need to update the column that are calculated from the column that are changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863449/how-can-i-refresh-the-grid-after-i-edit-the-kendo-ui-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use the [Sync](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-sync) event, not the RequestEnd event. Also, when you call the `read()` method of the DataSource, the `ReadRequestData` function is called to get a date and pass it to your `ExchangeRate_Read` action. But, after the data is updated you don't need that date. So, you can just clear the DateTimePicker.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(item => item.targetCurrency); 
    })
    .Events(events =>
    {
        events.Sync("onSync");  
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("ExchangeRate_Read", "MyController").Data("ReadRequestData"))
    .Update(c => c.Action("Currencies_Update", "MyControllor")) 
    ) 
)      

function onSync(e) {
    $("#dateList").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value('');
    $('#ExchangeGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
}
```

Now, in your `ExchangeRate_Read` action you can use the current date in case the date passed from the view is null.

Comment: Thank you. I have also added code for "data" in Controller:                           public ActionResult ExchangeRate_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string currencyName = "usd", string date = null)
{
    . . .
    if (date == null || date == string.Empty)
    {
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        date = dateNow.ToString();
    }

Comment: No, you have not. You have just up-voted my answer. You need to click on the check mark to mark it as answered.